# How to make a wrapped border maintain proportionality & how to crop images to be the same size & retain responsiveness? CSS, Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am struggling with the bootstrap's grid system. I want the blue border (.outer-link) to wrap the the images (.image-link) and maintain the same ratio to the images as the page changes size. I have the border separate from the image because I want both the image and the border to be rounded, but for there to be some padding between the image and the border. (I am open to a more effective way of doing this.)

Also, how can you get images of different original sizes to crop themselves to be the same size while still retaining their responsiveness?

```
    <section class="fluid-container m-3 justify-content-center">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-3 order-2 order-md-1 dish-image">
                    <a class="outer-link align-items-center" href="../maindishes/butternut-chili.html">
                        <img class="img-fluid image-link" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585029780574-65af8aa61abd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
                            alt="picture of dish">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h2 class="col-md-3 dish-name order-1 order-md-2 text-md-start text-center">
                    <a class="text-link" href="../maindishes/butternut-chili.html">Butternut Squash and Farro Chili</a>
                </h2>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-3 order-4 order-md-3 dish-image">
                    <a class="outer-link" href="../maindishes/african-stew.html">
                        <img class="img-fluid image-link" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582576163090-09d3b6f8a969?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80"
                            alt="picture of dish">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h2 id="african-stew"
                    class="col-md-3 dish-name dish-name-2 order-3 order-md-4 text-md-start text-center">
                    <a class="text-link" href="../maindishes/african-stew.html"> Slow Cooked North African Stew with
                        Couscous</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </section>
```

```
.outer-link {
    border: #2EC4B6 solid 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 0;
}

.image-link {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Adding `display: block` to your `outer-link` class will get the link to surround the image. For an artistic suggestion, try it with a larger radius (e.g. 10px) on the outer border.

Comment: Thanks! The larger radius on the outer border does look nicer.